# Logging into Gmail with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww01A.png)When I try to do anything with Gmail with Selenium webdriver, it locks me out because it is a controlled browser.  Has anyone found a way around this so that you can have your inbox open in a selenium controlled browser?

Comment: post the exact error message and/or screenshot here

Comment: @Villa_7 it is not an error in the code, it is just when you try to login to Gmail with Selenium controlled browser, Gmail does not let you sign in because it says this browser or app may not be secure.  I was just wondering if anyone found a way around it.  I put a screenshot of what it says in the question.

Comment: FYI, Google does provide a [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api).

Comment: @Keith , yes, I know but right now I am looking for a solution where I can log into it.